# How to detect type unstable functions in Julia

Tags: julia

**Setup:** Let's say I have a reasonably detailed piece of software (in Julia), involving the interaction of several modules. I feel like it is running slower than it should. Typically the [first culprit to check for is type unstable functions](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#write-type-stable-functions), i.e. functions where the compiler is unable to determine ahead of time what the output type will be.

**Question:** How can I detect these type unstable functions?

**What I currently do:** I use the profiling tools, e.g. the [ProfileView.jl](https://github.com/timholy/ProfileView.jl) package of @tholy, to detect bottlenecks, under the assumption that type unstable functions will show up here (due to their excessive run-time). But what would be really nice is some sort of debugging tool that, after a routine is run, will spit out a list of functions where the compiler was unable to determine the output type ahead of time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try [TypeCheck.jl](https://github.com/astrieanna/TypeCheck.jl) on bits the profiler say are slow.

Julia 0.4 has [@code_warntype](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#code-warntype) as well.

Comment: Huh. Somehow I was completely unaware of the TypeCheck package, nor did it show up in my search. That is exactly what I'm after :-)  Many thanks!

Comment: TypeCheck.jl isn't maintained anymore (the last update was 5 years ago). Do you have any ideas for alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the excellent suggestions of IainDunning, running julia with `--track-allocation=user` and analyzing the results with `analyze_malloc` from the [`Coverage`](https://github.com/IainNZ/Coverage.jl) package is a good way to quickly get a high-level overview. The principle is that type-instability triggers memory allocation, so looking for lines of code that have unexpected, large allocations is a good way to find the most egregious instances of type instability.

You can find more information about `track-allocation` [in the manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/profile/#Memory-allocation-analysis-1), and even more performance-analysis options [described](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/).